# Inputstream Load resource file in java 9

Tags: java

I have trouble with inputstreamreader in java 9 and inputstream, error is java.lang.NullPointerException, and related to proper resource location.

The calling code is in "default package" in src folder and the "resources" folder is a subfolder of "src", like this :

```
src
  -default package
  - ...
  -resources
```

With java 1.8, the code :

```
ClassLoader.class.getResourceAsStream("/resources/villes.csv" )
```

is properly working.

I have seen some answers here but don't know how to apply to my case.

Thank you for any help !

bb

Comment: Post full stack trace and a working example pls.

Comment: Have you tried `ClassLoader.class.getResourceAsStream("src/resources/villes.csv" )`?

Comment: @AmitabhaRoy Why do you want to know? Resources are not retrieved from the source folder, but from the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I've found a solution. Java 8 code is :

```
ClassLoader.class.getResourceAsStream("/resources/villes.csv" )
```

With Java 9 I needed to re^lace ClassLoader by the main class of the application, in my case "Calendrier" as ;

```
Calendrier.class.getResourceAsStream("/resources/villes.csv" )
```

bb